# sum up json values

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm trying to sum up all the values in the json that contain the string "Example". But I have no idea how to do it.
I'm using the "Newtonsoft.Json" framework.

```
 {
      "Example1344": 13,
      "Example925": 16,
      "Example454Example": 24,
      "Nothing": 51,
      "Other9235": 45
      }
```

So that the result would be 53

Comment: `I have no idea how to do it` You need to do some research.  This is not a tutorial service.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something along these lines might work for you:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim json As String = $"{{
          ""Example1344"": 13,
          ""Example925"": 16,
          ""Example454Example"": 24,
          ""Nothing"": 51,
          ""Other9235"": 45
          }}"

        Dim model As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim value As Int16 = 0

        value = model.Properties _
            .Where(Function(m) m.Name.Contains("Example")) _
            .Sum(Function(m) m.Value)

        Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {value}")

        Console.WriteLine("PRESS ANY KEY TO EXIT")
        Console.ReadKey(True)
    End Sub

End Module
```